# System of differential equations with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $x_1$, $x_2$ create the fundamental system of solutions of
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_1'=tx_1+x_2\sin(t+1)\\
> x_2'=x_1+t^2x_2
> \end{cases} \tag{1} \label{1}
> $$
> Check for which values of parameter $a\in \mathbb{R}$ functions $y_1=2x_1-ax_2$ and $y_2=ax_1-8x_2$ create the fundamental system of solutions of \eqref{1} too.

---

In order for $y_1$, $y_2$ to create the fundamental system of solutions, they must:

a) be a solution to \eqref{1}

b) be linearly independent
I checked b) from definion of linear independence and got that they are independent $\iff a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4;4\}$, but I don't know how to check a).

Also, checking my result for b) would be appreciated too.

Comment: Seems to me that the system is NOT independent for a=4 or a=-4. As for the point a) you just have to differentiate $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ and then substitute them to the equation, then use the fact that $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ satisfy (1) ... everything should cancel out.

Comment: @Salcio yeah I checked linear independence with two methods: calculating from definition I got that it's $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-4;4\}$, but when I tried to calculate it with determinant it simplified to $16\det \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$, which is non zero because $x_1$, $x_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: As for the second part, would it be enough to say that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linear combinations of the solutions $x_1$, $x_2$ and therefore they are solutions too?

Comment: Since the equation is linear with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ and the formulas are linear you are right. But in general case it is not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The system

$$
\cases{
x_1'=tx_1+x_2\sin(t+1)\\
x_2'=x_1+t^2x_2
}
$$

can be represented as $\mathcal{D}[x_1,x_2]=0$ and $\mathcal{D}[2x_1-ax_2,ax_1-8x_2]=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & -a\\ a&-8\end{array}\right)\mathcal{D}[x_1,x_2]=0$. This occurs uniquely when $a^2\ne 16$